# Fallo en consulta con PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy haciendo una consulta a una base de datos. En dicha consulta quiero consultar los resultados que están entre un rango de fechas, pero tengo el problema de que al hacer la consulta me dice:

```
ERROR SQL You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
   $fechahora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $nhora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fechahora) + 3600); 
   $consulta = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tareas WHERE estado = 0 AND avisar = 1 AND fecha_hora_aviso BETWEEN '$fechahora' AND '$nhora'");
```

//EDICION
Edito mi pregunta. El fallo no estaba ahi, el fallo estaba causado por el siguiente código:

```
$hora_aviso = date("H:i", strtotime($hora_aviso));
```

Y se ha solucionado simplemente cambiándolo por:

```
$hora_aviso = date('H:i', strtotime($hora_aviso));
```

Comment: Esa consulta no parece tener error de sintaxis. ¿Seguro que el mensaje de error se refiere al código que nos muestras en la pregunta? ¿Podrías agregar el mensaje de error completo, incluyendo la ruta del archivo, el número de línea, etc?

Comment: Vale, disculpas. Después de mucho depurar encontré el fallo y no estaba ahi. Edito mi pregunta para poner donde estaba por si a alguien más le pasa, Gracias.

Comment: Puesss tampoco es eso. ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre esto: `$hora_aviso = date("H:i", strtotime($hora_aviso));` y esto: `$hora_aviso = date('H:i', strtotime($hora_aviso));` de cara al error planteado? Te aconsejo que leas bien los mensajes de error para fines de depuración, los  mismos te dicen en qué archivo y en qué línea del mismo está fallando el código. La supuesta solución no tiene ningún sentido. El hecho es que se estaba creando una instrucción SQL errónea, pero no aparece el contexto real en que eso ocurre.

Comment: La diferencia es el uso de comitas simples o comitas dobles después de date(). De que no tenga ningún sentido, bueno respeto tu criterio, puede tener sentido o no para ti pero cambiando las comitas dobles por las simples se solucionó, que era el objetivo. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: La declaración de `$hora_aviso` produce el mismo resultado de las formas, lo puedes probar en un código aislado. El problema debería estar en otro sitio.